# Stateを継承したクラス内でのbuild外でのcontextの使用

Tags: flutter, dart

下記のコードはコンパイルできており、`context.go` も機能します。
わからないことは、このcontextはどこで宣言されているのか？です。

そこで、`print(context)` を出力させたところ以下のような内容でした。

```
test(dirty, state: _test#b8da0(lifecycle state: created))
```

宣言されていないcontext変数が使える理由がわかりません。

**該当のコード:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
class test extends Statefulwidget{@override State<test>createState()=>_test();}
class _test extends State<test>{
 void check(){context.go('/');}
 @override void initState(){super.initState();check();}
 @override Widget build(buildContext context){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

そういう仕様で実装されているということです。

詳細はAPIのヘルプを参照してください。
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/context.html

簡単に訳すと「StatefulWidget.createState で State オブジェクトを作成した後、initState を呼び出す前にBuildContext に関連付けます。この関連付けはdestroy が呼び出されるまで有効です。」

実装を見る限り、contextは_elementというStatefulElementを返しています。
これはcreateStateでState作成直後に設定されているようです。

このStatefulElementはElementの孫クラスになり、ElementでBuildContextをimplementsしているのでBuildContext としても使えるということになっています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: State<T extends StatefulWidget> classのプロパティにcontextがあったのですね。
build関数の引数buildContextを使う前から使えるということで納得しました。